# Set precise scroll position when pinch-zoomed in

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, pinchzoom

I'm creating a mapping app that places a marker image on a canvas and scrolls to it. I'm using the browser's pinch zooming and scrolling to zoom in/out of the map. However, I've noticed that there's some bizarre behavior, and I'm wondering how to get around it.

This is a little tough to explain, but here we go.

Let's imagine that you're at the standard zoom level on a webpage (you can't zoom out any further). Let's imagine that the area your browser window is showing is the "invisible box". There's some stuff you can see, and some stuff that's out of view (that you need to scroll to get to). Once you pinch-zoom in, the browser still pretends that your viewport is still at 100% zoom (i.e. Your browser is essentially cropping into that invisible box, but the invisible box stays in the same place.) Any JS on the page sees the scroll position as the same, no matter where you pan around *within the invisible box*. However, once you scroll to the edge, you start to *push* the edges of the invisible box. If you use JS to set the scroll position (`window.scrollTo(xPos, yPos)`), it sets the position of the invisible box, but the portion of the invisible box you *see* is still relative. This means that if you set the scroll position to (0,0) and your cropped-in view is not at the precise top left of the invisible box, the portion you see will NOT be at (0,0).

The issue I'm having is that I need to move the zoomed-in view to a specific spot. Since setting the position of the invisible box isn't really working, is there a way to force the browser to get rid of the invisible box, pinch-zoom all the way out, or maybe detect where the zoomed-in portion is within the invisible box? I'm stumped.