# Browser Zoom changes window.scrollTop/ document.scrollTop behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll, zooming

I'm trying to read the current y-scroll of a page to fadeIn/out elements while the user scrolls past them.

I tried many different solutions from this site, things like .scrollTop, .pageYOffset, .scrollY etc. , with $(window) and $(document), $("element"), convert it to percentage and so on...

First they all work fine, But when I zoom in the browser, the results I get change each time:

I have this simple setup as a page

```html
<div style="height: 800px"></div>
<h1 style="" id="test"> Test </h1>
<div style="height: 2000px"></div>
```

and for example this to read the scroll position:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
console.log($(this).scrollTop());
```

When I scroll down to my header and go just above the T of Test it says 830px.
But when I zoom in (tried chrome and firefox), first of all my console stops giving continous values and seems to get laggy(?) and going to the same place (right above the T) returns a different value (smaller when zooming in) depending on my zoom, so for example 500px.

Is there a solution to this, or Is there maybe another approach to achieve what I'm trying to do?

#### Additional information

- After more reading I know also see the difference between Zooming with Ctrl+/- (e.g. changing the font-size) and zooming by using my touchpad and 2 fingers. That also changes the results I get, so sometimes the element appears when window.scrollY returns 800px and sometimes it starts appearing when it says 300px. I'm getting more and more confused by this, maybe someone can help me with be basics here ;)
- Came across this : this, [Set precise scroll position when pinch-zoomed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534304/set-precise-scroll-position-when-pinch-zoomed-in) sounds kind of what I'm experiencing.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

My Question is obsolete.

After reading more about browser zoom vs OS zooming, pixel vs pixelDensity etc.

it all makes sense now.